# response.css Scrapy command returns no results even though the objects exists (python)

Tags: python, css, scrapy, web-crawler, spyder

##### The url i'm trying to colect info is this one:

`https://www.abf.com.br/a-abf/franquias-associadas-abf/`

##### CSS objects examples:

- this one is **ok**, scrapy returns the objects: `.list-francises`
- this one is **not ok**, scrapy returns an empty list: `.card-all-franchises div:nth-child(1)`

##### I'm running these commands:

`> scrapy shell 'https://www.abf.com.br/a-abf/franquias-associadas-abf/'`

(opens the scrapy shell in my vscode terminal)

`> response.css('.list-francises').getall()`

(returns the list of objects)

`> response.css('.card-all-franchises div:nth-child(1)').getall()`

(returns an empty list)

I tried to crawl at least three other websites and none of them had this type of unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the inner listing that you are trying to scrape is injected into the page from and ajax call.

This is the url for just the listing:

```
start_urls = ['https://central.portaldofranchising.com.br/word-press-abf/franquias/lista']
```

And using that url you can use your original css expression and it will work fine.

```
def parse(self, response):
    franchises = response.css('.card-all-franchises div:nth-child(1)::text').getall()
    yield {"franchises": franchises}
```

OUTPUT

```
2022-10-02 20:53:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-10-02 20:53:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-10-02 20:53:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-10-02 20:53:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-10-02 20:53:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-10-02 20:53:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
<Deferred at 0x17050846080>
2022-10-02 20:53:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://central.portaldofranchising.com.br/word-press-abf/franquias/lista> (referer: None)
2022-10-02 20:53:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://central.portaldofranchising.com.br/word-press-abf/franquias/lista>
{'franchises': [" ALENEK'S A PIZZA DA CAPITÃ", ' AMAZON SPA', ' DELTA BUSINESS COWORKING', ' GIRALOOK BRECHÓ INFANTIL', ' THE GOOD COP Donut Shop', ' U V ULTRA VISÃO PERÍCIAS VISTORIAS AUTOMOTIVAS', '+ÁGI
L', '10 PASTÉIS', '22 SPECIAL COFFEE ', '33DOCTOR', '430 GRADI', '4BEER FRANQUIAS', '4EN SAÚDE', '5ÀSEC', '60 MINUTOS LAVANDERIA SELF-SERVICE', 'A FÓRMULA', 'ABC DA CONSTRUÇÃO', 'ABY´S SPORT', 'ACADEMIA D
E INGLÊS WASHINGTON', 'ACADEMIA GAVIÕES', 'AÇAÍ BEAT', 'AÇAÍ CONCEPT', 'AÇAÍ DA BARRA', 'AÇAÍ NO KILO ', 'AÇAÍ PURÍSSIMO ', 'AÇAÍ SUNSET', 'AÇAILAND ', 'ACCORHOTELS', 'ACELERA CAR', 'ACESSO SAÚDE', 'ACG H
OME CARE ', 'ACHEI NO PÃO', 'ACIUM', 'ACQIO', 'ACQUA AROMA', 'ACQUAZERO', 'ACTIONCOACH BRASIL', 'ACUIDAR', 'ACVIDA', 'AD CLINIC ESTÉTICA E BEM-ESTAR', 'ADCOS', 'ADONAI RH', 'AF CRÉDITO SOLUÇÕES FINANCEIRA
S', 'AGAXTUR VIAGENS', 'AGGRO NUTRIÇÃO INTELIGENTE NO CAMPO', 'AGILITY', 'AGRO ATLAS BRASIL', 'ÁGUA DE CHEIRO', 'ÁGUA DOCE CACHAÇARIA', 'ALBERT´S', 'ALÉM DO OLHAR', 'ALERGOSHOP', 'ALGAR TELECOM', 'ALL NET
 NUCLEO DE FORMAÇAO PROFISSIONAL', 'ALL PÉ - REVENDEDOR AUTORIZADO DR. SCHOLL´S®', 'ALPHA FITNESS', 'ALPHABETO', 'ALPHAGRAPHICS', 'AM/PM', 'AMÁVIA COSMÉTICOS', 'AMBEV - CHOPP BRAHMA EXPRESS', 'AMBEV - QUI
OSQUE CHOPP BRAHMA', 'AMERICAN BURGUER', 'AMERICAN COOKIES', 'AMERICANA SAÚDE', 'AMERICANAS DELIVERY', 'AMEY', 'AMIGLISS ', 'AMISTE CAFÉ', 'AMO SOBRANCELHAS', 'AMO VACINAS', 'AMOR & CUIDADO', 'AMOR AOS PE
DAÇOS', 'ANA TERRA SEGUROS', 'ANACAPRI', 'ANEETHUN', 'ANIMAL PLACE', 'ANIMALIAFARMA', 'ANJOS COLCHÕES', 'ANNE CAROLINE GLOBAL', 'APK CLUBE ', 'APOLAR IMÓVEIS', 'APRIORI ENERGIA', 'AQUAMAGIC', 'ARABIA EXPR
ESS', "ARABI'S ESFIHARIA", 'ARAMIS MENSAWEAR', 'AREZZO', 'ARMAZEM FIT STORE', 'ARRANJOS EXPRESS', 'ARTES FILMES', 'ARTEX', 'ARTVIDA FARMÁCIA DE MANIPULAÇÃO', 'ARTWALK', 'ASANKA', 'ASCOBS ', 'ASCONA KIDS',
 'ASTRAL', 'ATENA FRANCHISING', 'ATENDE PORTARIA ', 'ATHUS', 'ATITUDE POINT', 'ATIVA SOLUÇÕES EMPRESARIAIS', 'ATMO MÍDIA DIGITAL CORPORATIVA', 'AUDACES', 'AUTHENTIC FEET', 'AUXILIADORA PREDIAL', 'AVATIM',
 'AVOICE FORMATURAS', 'B.LEM PADARIA PORTUGUESA', 'BABBO GIOVANNI FRANQUIAS', 'BABLE PET', 'BABY DUCK', 'BABY GYM ACADEMIA PARA BEBÊS', "BAFF'S SALGADERIA", 'BAGAGGIO', 'BALADA MIX', 'BALANCEADO', 'BALI Ó
TICAS ', 'BALONE', 'BANANA FOOD', 'BAR DO URSO', 'BARBARESCO EXPRESS', 'BARBEARIA DOM HÉLIO', 'BARELA', 'BATATA SHOW', 'BATERAS BEAT MUSIC SCHOOL', 'BAZACON', 'BEAUTY B', 'BEAUTYLINE', 'BEAUTYPARIS', 'BEB
ELU SANDUÍCHES', 'BEBIDAS ONLINE', 'BEETOOLS, THE LANGUAGE SCHOOL', 'BELA RUSSA', 'BELGO CERCAS', 'BELLA CAPRI PIZZARIA', 'BELLA GULA', 'BELLAZA', 'BELLE.CLUB', 'BELLIOTICA', 'BEM SAFE', 'BENDITO COOKIES
E BROWNIES', 'BERLITZ', 'BIBI', 'BIDONCRED', 'BIJU DA CHICA ', 'BILLY THE GRILL', 'BIO MUNDO', 'BIOCENTRO ', 'BIOFLORA', 'BISCOITÊ', 'BIUP SEJA MAIS', 'BLUE SOL', 'BLUEFIT', 'BLUEPEX', 'BMZ AUTO BROKERS',
 'BOALI', 'BOATLUX COTAS NÁUTICAS ', 'BOB´S', 'BOCATTINO BOX', 'BODY FOR SURE', 'BODYCONCEPT', 'BOLO DA MADRE', 'BOLOGNAS', 'BOLOS DO CERRADO', 'BONAPARTE', 'BONASECCO', 'BONO PNEUS', 'BORA BRASIL MOBILID
ADE URBANA', 'BOTOCENTER', 'BOULANGERIE CARIOCA', 'BOX MINEIRO DELIVERY', 'BR MANIA', 'BR MULTAS SOLUÇÕES EM TRÂNSITO', 'BRASIL CANADÁ - EDUCAÇÃO BILÍNGUE', 'BRASIL NUTRI SHOP', 'BRASILEIRINHO DELIVERY CO
MIDA TÍPICA', 'BRASTEMP', 'BRAZIL HEALTH', 'BRCONDOS', 'BRED CAPAS', 'BRITISH AND AMERICAN', 'BROOMER MEN´S WEAR', 'BROWBAR - BAR DE SOBRANCELHA', 'BRUMED MEDICINA E ENGENHARIA DO TRABALHO', 'BUBBLE MIX T
EA', 'BUBBLEKILL', 'BUCKINGHAM PARFUMS', 'BUDDHA SPA', 'BURGER KING BRASIL', 'BUSCA CLIENTES', 'CACAU NOIR', 'CACAU SHOW', 'CACHORREIROS', 'CAFÉ CULTURA', 'CAFÉ DO FEIRANTE', 'CAFÉ DO PONTO', 'CAFÉ DU CEN
TRE', 'CAKECH', 'CALIFORNIA COFFEE', 'CALZOON MINI CALZONES', 'CAMARÃO & CIA', 'CAMERITE', 'CAMES BRASIL', 'CAMISARIA FMW', 'CAMPINAS CELULARES FRANQUIAS', 'CANDICE CIGAR CO', 'CANTINHO DA COXINHA FRANQUI
AS', 'CAPILÉ', 'CAPITANO', 'CAPODARTE', 'CARACOL CHOCOLATES', 'CARICANECAS', 'CARMEN STEFFENS', 'CAROL COXINHAS ', 'CARTAO EXAME BR', 'CARTÓRIO BRASIL E MUNDO', 'CASA BAUDUCCO', 'CASA DA OMA MORADA PARA I
DOSAS(OS)', 'CASA DAS CUECAS', 'CASA DE BOLOS', 'CASA DO CELULAR', 'CASA DO CONSTRUTOR', 'CASA DO NOTEBOOK', 'CASA DO PÃO DE QUEIJO', 'CASA DO SONO ', 'CASA ESCRITORIO SEMPRE LIMPO', 'CASA PILÃO', 'CASA P
RADO', 'CASA REVIVA ', 'CASAGROUP', 'CASE & SCREEN', 'CASINHA DE CÍLIOS ', 'CASTOR', 'CASTSEG DISTRIBUIDORA', 'CATARINENSE IMPLANTES', 'CAXIASMED FRANCHISING', 'CCAA', "C'CLEAN LAVANDERIA SELF-SERVICE", '
CEBRAC - CENTRO BRASILEIRO DE CURSOS', 'CENTER PANOS', 'CENTRO BRITÂNICO', 'CENTRO NUTRA GERENCIAMENTO DE PESO', 'CEOFOOD', 'CEOPAG', 'CEPIL LASER ', 'CERVEJARIA DOGMA', 'CF CONTABILIDADE', 'CHAT IN ENGLI
SH', 'CHEF DA EMPADA', 'CHEFLERA', 'CHICKEN TOWN', 'CHILLI BEANS', 'CHINA IN BOX', 'CHIQUINHO SORVETES', 'CHOCO OZ', 'CHOCOLATES BRASIL CACAU', 'CHOPE DO MESTRE', 'CHOPP TIME', 'CHORIPAN', 'CHURRAS EXPRES
S', 'CHURROS DA CALAIS ', 'CI', 'CIA DAS DIARISTAS', 'CIA MARITIMA', 'CL JOIAS', 'CLEANNEW', 'CLEANNOW', 'CLINICA BIAVATTI', 'CLINICA CONSULTARE', 'CLÍNICA DA CIDADE', 'CLINICA VETERINÁRIA APAIXONADOS POR
 QUATRO PATAS', 'CLINICAO VETERINARIA', 'CLINICASEPUA', 'CLUBE DE PERMUTA', 'CLUBE MELISSA', 'CLUBE MORENA ROSA', 'CLUBE TURISMO', 'CMBRASIL', 'CNA', 'CODEBUDDY', 'CÓDIGO GIRLS', 'COIFE ODONTO', 'COLCCI',
 'COLCHOES DOCTORS', 'COLCHÕES ORTOBOM', 'COLÉGIO FORÇA MÁXIMA', 'COLOLIDO', 'COMPANHIA DA FÓRMULA', 'COMPANHIA DO CHURRASCO', 'COMPRE CERTO REDE DE DROGARIAS', 'CONCRETTA ', 'CONFIANCE ', 'CONGELATTO CAF
FE', 'CONNECT ENERGIA SOLAR', 'CONSTANCE', 'CONSTRUTORA UNIÃO', 'CONSULTING NOW', 'CONTA4U ', 'CONTAINER SEGURANÇA', 'CONTEL', 'CONVEX BRASIL', 'COOKIE STORIES', 'COR & UNHA LTDA', 'CORREIOS', 'COSECHAS',
 'COXINHA NO POTE', 'CPEA CENTRO PAULISTA DE ESTUDOS EM AGRONEGÓCIO', 'CREAM BERRY', 'CREAMY CAKE', 'CREDBIZ', 'CREDIALL SOLUÇÕES', 'CREDISOL BRASIL', 'CRIAMIGOS OFICINA DE URSOS', 'CRIATIVANDO WALLPAPERS
', 'CROASONHO', 'CROSS EXPERIENCE', 'CROSSBOX', 'CTRL+PLAY', 'CUIDANDO MAIS', 'CUIDARE CUIDADORES DE PESSOAS ', 'CULTURA INGLESA', 'CUORDICREMA', 'CUTELARIA D’AVILA', 'CVC BRASIL', 'CYMACO', 'D3B ', 'DA G
ENTILI', 'DANI.HOLZBACH', 'DANK IDIOMAS', 'DANKI MODA', 'DAVANT ODONTOLOGIA E IMPLANTES', 'DCREDITOS', 'DECO SKIN', 'DECORAMAX', 'DEEP FREEZE', 'DEKRA', 'DELLA VIA PNEUS', 'DELTAEXPRESSO', 'DENTAL ARTE',
'DENTZ', 'DEO VITA SAÚDE INTELIGENTE', 'DEPILA +', 'DEPILE-SE', 'DEPYL ACTION', 'DERMAGE', 'DESINFLEX CONTROLE DE PRAGAS URBANAS', 'DETROIT STEAKHOUSE', 'DF DR. FISCAL', 'DI BLASI PIZZAS ARTESANAIS', 'DI
SANTINNI', 'DIA%', 'DIAS MARQUES', 'DÍDIO PIZZA', 'DIOLASER', 'DIRECT MARKETING DIGITAL', 'DISAPAR / BASICOISAS', 'DISENSA', 'DIVINA TERRA', 'DIVINO FOGÃO - COMIDA DA FAZENDA', 'DOCCTOR MED CLÍNICA MÉDICA
 PARTICULAR', 'DOCG.  AUTHENTIC PET', 'DOCTOR FEET', 'DOCTORFIT', 'DÓFFEE DONUTS & COFFEE', 'DOG KING', 'DOIS MINUTOS RASTREAMENTO', 'DOMINO`S PIZZA', 'DON CIOTTO GELATO NA CHAPA', 'DONAFRESCA PESCADOS',
'DONATÁRIO', 'DONNA MARIA ', 'DORTPREV', 'DOTZ', 'DOUTOR HERNIA', 'DOUTOR RESOLVE', 'DOUTOR SOFÁ', 'DOUTORES DA ESTÉTICA', 'DOUTORES DA WEB', 'DR HARMONIZA', 'DR. EXAME', 'DR. LASER', 'DR. SHAPE', 'DRA. M
EI', 'DROGARIA MEDFACIL', 'DROGARIA MINIPREÇO', 'DROGARIA SANTA MARTA FRANQUIA', 'DROGARIAS FARMAGNUS', 'DROGARIAS MAX', 'DROGARIAS ÓTIMA FARMA', 'DROGASHOP', 'DROGAVET', 'DROPS DE MENTA', 'DROPS MOTÉIS',
 'Drs. protect', 'DRYCLEAN USA', 'DRYJET', 'DRYWASH', 'DSOP', 'DUCKBILL COOKIES AND COFFE', 'D-UNHAS', 'É SEGURO CORRETORA', 'EAGLE TRACK', 'EAT ASIA ', 'ECHOSIS', 'ECODECOR', 'ECOPOWER ENERGIA SOLAR', 'E
COVILLE', 'EDANBANK', 'E-FIT ELECTRO FITNESS', 'EKIM SEMIJOIAS ', 'ELAV LAVANDERIA', 'ELEVOR', 'ELFEN ', 'ELITE PROFESSIONAL - MELHORAMENTOS ', 'EMAGRECENTRO', 'EMIVE FRANCHISING', 'EMPADA BRASIL', 'EMPAD
INHAS BARNABE', 'EMPÓRIO DÖLL', 'EMPÓRIO ESSENZA', 'EMPORIO FADAS MAGRINHAS', 'EMPÓRIO MINEIRO CHEIRIN BÃO', 'EMPORIUM DA BELEZA', 'EMPRESTA BEM MELHOR', 'ENCONTRE SUA VIAGEM', 'ENDOSSA ', 'ENERG GERADORE
S', 'ENERGY BRASIL', 'ENGENHEIROS DO SOL', 'ENJOY', 'ENSINA MAIS', 'ESCAPE60', 'ESCOLA DE GASTRONOMIA CHEF GOURMET ', 'ESCOLA DO MECÂNICO', 'ESCOLA FLAMENGO', 'ESCOLA GUGA TENIS', 'ESPAÇOLASER', 'ESPECIAL
ISTA VISTORIAS', 'ESPETINHO BOM', 'ESPETINHOS MIMI', 'ESPETTO CARIOCA', 'ESTETIC 360', 'ESTETIC FACE', 'ESTETIC PREMIUM', 'ESTETIK KV ®', 'ESTIVANELLI', 'ESTRELA BEAUTY', 'ESTUDIOFACE', 'EU AMO CONDOMINIO
', 'EURO COLCHÕES', 'EVIDENTE', 'EVOKE', 'EVYDHENCE PERÍCIA AUTOMOTIVA', 'EX BURGUER', 'EXCLUSIVE DIAMOND FRANCHISING', 'EXPENSE REDUCTION ANALYSTS - E.R.A BRASIL', 'EXPERIMENTO', 'EX-TOURO', 'FÁBRICA DE
BOLO VÓ ALZIRA', 'FABRICA DI CHOCOLATE', 'FACE DOCTOR', 'FACEPRIME', 'FACTA', 'FALCON ARMAS', 'FARMA & FARMA', 'FARMA CONDE', 'FARMÁCIA ARTESANAL', 'FARMÁCIA PERSONALE ', 'FARMÁCIA ROVAL', 'FARMACIAS BRAS
IL POUPA LAR', 'FARMÁCIAS SÃO RAFAEL', 'FARMATOTAL', 'FARMELHOR', 'FAST AÇAÍ', 'FAST ESCOVA', 'FAST TELEPIZZA', 'FAST4YOU HOME MARKET', 'FASTFRAME - MOLDURA NA HORA', 'FEDERAL INVEST', 'FENÓTIPO ENGENHARI
A', 'FERROVIA', 'FIADORWEB ', 'FICHIPS FOOD', 'FINGER MÓVEIS PLANEJADOS', 'FINI', 'FIOLASER SPA', 'FIRST CLASS', 'FISIO CARE PET', 'FISK CENTRO DE ENSINO', 'FITLAND', 'FIVE NEGOCIOS', 'FLAMY FRANQUIAS', '
FLASH COURIER', 'FLYTOUR FRANCHISING', 'FLYWORLD O SEU AMIGO DE VIAGENS', 'FNP ', 'FOLKS FRANQUEADORA', 'FOM', 'FOOD BRANDS', 'FOR RENTAL', 'FÓRMULA ACADEMIA', 'FÓRMULA ANIMAL', 'FORNERIA AHAM', 'FORSEED'
, 'FORUM', 'FRANCHISING GROUP', 'FRANGO AMERICANO BRASIL GESTAO DE ATIVOS', 'FRANGO NO POTE', 'FRANKLIN COVEY', 'FREE FARO', 'FRIDA UNDERWEAR', 'FRITIS', 'FUEL THE EYEWEAR COMPANY', 'GARAGEM BARBA CABELO
E BEM ESTAR', 'GAZIN SEMIJOIAS', 'GEAAP AGROCIÊNCIAS', 'GECON GESTÃO DE CONDOMÍNIOS & FRANCHISING', 'GELA BOCA SORVETES', 'GELATO BORELLI ', 'GENDAI JAPANESE FAST FOOD', 'GENERAL PRIME BURGER', 'GEO CREDI
 BNK SOLUÇÕES FINANCEIRAS', 'GET IT', 'GIGATRON', 'GINÁSTICA DO CÉREBRO', 'GIOLASER', 'GIRAFFAS', 'GO COFFEE ', 'GO JUICE', 'GOLDEN MIX ÓTICA', 'GOLDEN SUCOS', 'GOLFRAN', 'GOLLOG', 'GONEXT FRANQUIA', 'GOO
LA AÇAÍ', 'GORDÃO LANCHES', 'GOU', 'GRACOM', 'GRAND CRU', 'Grandvision By Fototica', 'GRANERO', 'GRÃO ESPRESSO CAFETERIA', 'GRAU T - CENTRO DE ENSINO TÉCNICO', 'GRAVIOLA', 'GREEN BY MISSAKO', 'GREEN STATI
ON', 'GRID TIE SOLAR', 'GRILETTO', 'GRUPO ACOLHER & CUIDAR', 'GRUPO BIAGI FRANCHISING', 'GRUPO FR VENDAS', 'GRUPO GINGA', 'GRUPO MEDNET MEDICINA E SEGURANÇA DO TRABALHO', 'GUA.CO', 'GUACAMOLE', 'GUARDE MA
IS', 'GUD FUD', 'GUIA-SE', 'HABIB´S', 'HAPPY HUB EDUCACIONAL', 'HAPPY&CO.®️', 'HARO SUSHI ', 'HASHI EXPRESS', 'HAUSZ PISOS E AMBIENTES', 'HAUX CLINIC', 'HAVAIANAS', 'HAVANNA', 'HCC ENERGIA SOLAR', 'HEILIG
E POCKET', 'HELIAR', 'HELLOO', 'HELP RECURSOS', 'HELP! LOJA DE CRÉDITO', 'HELPDIGITAL TECNOLOGIA', 'HENRIMAR ', 'HERING KIDS', 'HERING STORE', 'HEY PEPPERS', 'HIGH TORQUE CAR SERVICE', 'HIGHSTIL', 'HINODE
', 'HIPERFESTA', 'HOKEN', 'HOME ANGELS', 'HOMECARE DOS ÓCULOS', 'HOMEHUB', 'HONEST MARKET BRASIL', 'HOPE LINGERIE', 'HÓRUS ENERGIA SOLAR FOTOVOLTÁICA', 'HOSTNET', 'HOT DOGGERY', "HOT N' TENDER", 'HOTEL 10
', 'HOUSE OF SAMSONITE', 'HSH - HOME SUSHI HOME', 'HUB ODONTO', 'HYPERLOCAL ', 'I RIO ODONTO', 'IC INSTITUTO DA CONSTRUÇÃO FORMAÇÃO PROFISSIONAL', 'ICE CREAMY SORVETES', 'ICEMELLOW SORVETES E CIA', 'IDEAL
 CRED MARKETING LTDA (BR/RS)', 'IE INTERCÂMBIO NO EXTERIOR', 'IEneagrama', 'IEV - INSTITUTO DE ESPECIALIZAÇÃO EM VENDAS', 'IFINANCE', 'IGA', 'IGUI', 'IMAGINARIUM', 'IMÓVEIS CRÉDITO REAL', 'IMPACTO PRIME',
 'INFINITIBANK PRIME', 'INFLUX ENGLISH SCHOOL', 'INFORMATION PLANET', 'INSOLE', 'INSPIRAR', 'INSTITUTO ANA HICKMANN', 'INSTITUTO BRASILEIRO DE LÍNGUAS', 'INSTITUTO DOS ÓCULOS', 'INSTITUTO EMBELLEZE', 'INS
TITUTO GOURMET FORMAÇÃO PROFISSIONAL', 'INSTITUTO L´ORÉAL PROFESSIONNEL', 'INSTITUTO NEW PILATES', 'INSTITUTO TRATA - JOELHO E QUADRIL', 'INSTITUTO VISÃO SOLIDÁRIA', 'INTERAG', 'INTIMISSIMI', "INVERNO D'I
TALIA COFFEE", 'IOA', 'IÓCULOS', 'IP SCHOOL INGLÊS PARTICULAR', 'IPATRE', 'IRO', 'ISLA BOLSAS', 'ISP SAÚDE', 'ITC VERTEBRAL', 'ITCASE', "IT'S BANK", "IT'S GRILL EXPRESS", 'IW INGLÊS SEM ENROLAÇÃO', 'J7 SO
LAR ENERGY', 'JACK CHICKEN DELIVERY', 'JADLOG', 'JAH', 'JALECA', 'JAN ROSÊ', 'JANELA BAR', 'JANI KING', 'JAN-PRO', 'JECA TATU COMIDA BRASILEIRA', 'JET OIL', 'JIN JIN', 'JOANINHA BRECHO INFANTIL ', 'JOGÊ L
INGERIE', 'JOHNNY ROCKETS', 'JORGE BISCHOFF', 'JOVEM VALOR', 'JP ODONTO', 'JULIANA MANZINI', 'JUMPER PROFISSÕES E IDIOMAS LTDA', 'JÚPITER', 'KAINGÓ', 'KAZ ', 'KEKALA CUSTOM PICOLÉ', 'KFC', 'KIICHI', 'KING
CASE', 'KINGDOM AÇAÍ', 'KINGS SNEAKERS', 'KINSOL ENERGIAS RENOVÁVEIS', 'KLIN', 'KNN IDIOMAS', 'KONI STORE', 'KOOKABU', 'KOPENHAGEN', 'KORIN', 'KUMON', 'L`ENTRECÔTE DE PARIS', 'LA MAFIA BARBEARIA SOCIAL CL
UB', 'LA PASTA GIALLA', 'LA SANTÉ', 'LAAV SERVIÇOS AUTOMOTIVOS. ', 'Laboratório G.Góes', 'LADY PERFUMARIA', 'LAPIS DE COR', 'LAUNDROMAT', 'LAVA E LEVA LAVANDERIA', 'LAVATERIA', 'LAVO', 'LE BISCUIT', 'LE B
RIJU', 'LE PETIT MACARONS', 'LEARDI', 'LEBONTON', 'LEDSELEDS', 'LEGACY FRANCHISING', 'LEMAX HAMBURGUERIA', "LET'S EAT BURGUER 'N' BAR", 'LEVE', 'LEZ A LEZ', 'LIBERO CORRETORA', 'LIBRE ELETROESTIMULAÇÃO',
'LIEN CORRETORA DE SEGUROS', 'LIFE BRASIL FRANCHISING', 'LIFE SORRISOS', 'LIG LIG DELIVERY', 'LIGHT FOOD WAY', 'LILICA & TIGOR', 'LIMPEZA COM ZELO', 'LIMPIDUS', 'LIMPPO MULTISERVIÇOS', 'LINK MONITORAMENTO
', 'LITTLE KICKERS', 'LIVRARIA E PAPELARIA NOBEL', 'LIZ LINGERIE', 'LOARA', 'LOCALIZA', "L'OCCITANE", 'LOCEXPRESS', 'LOFT', 'LOJA DO DINO', 'LOPES', 'LORD', 'LOS MEX COCINA MEXICANA', 'LOS NETO', 'LOUCOS
POR COXINHA', 'LOVE BRANDS', 'LOVE GIFTS', 'LUBRAX +', 'LUGANO CHOCOLATES ARTESANAIS', "LUG'S", 'LUKRO', 'LUMINOVA', 'LUPO', 'LZ FILMS', 'MAG PAPELARIA', 'MAGIC FEET', 'MAGRASS', 'MAHOGANY', 'MAID FOR YOU
', 'MAIL BOXES ETC.', 'MAIS NATURAL', 'MAIS TOP ESTÉTICA', 'MAIS1', 'MAISLASER DEPILAÇÃO', 'MAJÔ BEAUTY CLUB', 'MALWEE KIDS', 'MAMMA MIA EXPRESS', 'MANA POKE', 'MANAGER', 'MANÉ RIO', 'MANIA DE CHURRASCO!
PRIME STEAK HOUSE', 'MAPA DA MINA', 'MAPCELL FRANQUIAS', 'MAPLE BEAR', 'MARCENARIA DO FUTURO', 'MARDELLE', 'MARIA BRASILEIRA', 'MARIA FILÓ', 'MARIA LAVADEIRA', 'MARIA PITANGA AÇAITERIA', 'MARISOL', 'MARK
HAMBURGUERIA', 'MARKET4U', 'MARY HELP', 'MAX SUSHI JAPANESE FOOD', 'MAXIPAS', 'MAXSORRISO ', 'MAYBELLINE NEW YORK ', 'MAZZE SEMI JOIAS', 'MCDONALD´S', 'MEDIÇÃO - SOLUÇÕES METROLÓGICAS INTEGRADAS', 'MEDICM
AIS ', 'MEGAMATTE', 'MELTEN CO', 'MENU POKE', 'MERCADÃO DOS ÓCULOS', 'MERCADÃO PET', 'MERCADO DAS TINTAS', 'MESTRE DA OBRA ', 'MESTRE-CERVEJEIRO.COM', 'MEU CHAPA', 'MEU DEVER DE CASA', 'MEUS CÍLIOS', 'MIC
ROLINS', 'MILKY MOO MILKSHAKES', 'MILON', 'MINDS ENGLISH SCHOOL', 'MINEIRO DELIVERY', 'MINHA LAVANDERIA', 'MINHA PORTARIA', 'MINI DONUTS ', 'MINI KALZONE', 'MINI MELISSA CLUBE ', 'MINI ORBE-O GELATO DO FU
TURO', 'MISTER MULTAS', 'MISTER PIZZA', 'MMARTAN', 'MOBLY', 'MOCELIN FRANCHISING', 'MOLDURA MINUTO', 'MOLECAGGIO PIZZAS', 'MOMÊ AÇAÍ', 'MONCLOA', 'MONITORIAS', 'MONSTER DOG', 'MONTANA GRILL', 'MORANA', 'M
ORDIDELA', 'MORGAN', 'MORMAII FITNESS', 'MOZZA', 'MR CHEFF GASTRONOMIA', 'MR JEFF', 'MR. BLACK CAFÉ GOURMET', 'MR. CAT', 'MR. CHENEY COOKIES', 'MR. HOPPY', 'MR. KIDS', 'MR. MIX - MILK SHAKES', 'MR. PRETZE
LS', 'MTCRED', 'MULHERES HABILITADAS ', 'MULTICOISAS', 'MULTIFILMES WINDOW FILM', 'MULTIPLY CONSULTORIA', 'MULTSAÚDE BENEFÍCIOS', 'MUNDIAL EDITORA', 'MUNDO A PARTE', 'MUNDO ANIMAL LANCHONETE TEMÁTICA', 'M
UNDO TERRA', 'MUNDO VERDE', 'MUNIZ AUTOCENTER', 'MY COOKIES', 'MY PLACE OFFICE', 'MY ROBOT SCHOOL', 'MYLASH', 'NAÇÃO VERDE', 'NACIONAL SOL ENERGIA INTELIGENTE', 'NAILS2YOU ESMALTERIA E ESTÉTICA', 'NAJAH R
ÃO', 'NANI SOUND ', 'NANICA', 'NÃO+PELO', 'NETCALLCENTER', 'NEW ERA', 'NEW LINE PORTARIA REMOTA', 'NEWCASTLE ENGLISH CENTER', 'NEXT TECNOLOGIA DA INFORMAÇÃO', 'NHÔ SORVETES', 'NIVEL A', 'NOHA SHOES', 'NOO
MA ', 'NORWAYBANK', 'NOVISSA JOIAS', 'NOVOFIO TRATAMENTOS CAPILARES', 'NOW NUTRIÇÃO ESPORTIVA', 'NOXTEC', 'NTW CONTABILIDADE E GESTÃO EMPRESARIAL', 'NUBELLE', 'NUMBER ONE CHICKEN', 'NUTRIMAIS', 'NUTRON',
'NUTTY BAVARIAN', 'NUVNUV', 'NYS COLLECTION', 'O BOTICÁRIO', 'O BURGUÊS', 'O FORNÊS PIZZARIA DELIVERY', 'O2 HIPERBÁRICA', 'OAKBERRY AÇAÍ BOWLS', 'OASIS', 'OCA DE SAVÓIA', 'OCULUM ', 'OCXO', 'ODONTIC CLÍNI
CA ODONTOLÓGICA', 'ODONTO CENTER', 'ODONTO SPECIAL', 'ODONTOCLINIC', 'ODONTOCOMPANY', 'ODONTOLATINA', 'ODONTOTOP HOSPITAL DO DENTE', 'ODONTO-VIDA', 'OGGI SORVETES', 'OHTC OMNI HYPNOSIS TRAINING CENTER EST
. 1979', 'OI', 'OJO', 'OLHAR CERTO', 'OLHO VIVO', 'OLHO VIVO VISTORIAS', 'OMIE', 'OMO LAVANDERIA', 'ON BYTE', 'ONLINE TRADERS ', 'ONLOG', 'ONLY MULE MULERIA', 'ONODERA ESTÉTICA', 'OPENLASER', 'OPT ÓCULOS'
, 'ÓPTICA CENTER BY RCP', 'ÓPTICA DI FIORI', 'ORAL BRASIL', 'ORAL SIN IMPLANTES', 'ORAL UNIC IMPLANTES', 'ORALJET', 'ORGÂNICA BODY SPA', 'ORTHOCLÍNICAS', 'ORTHOCRIN', 'ORTHODENT CLÍNICA ODONTOLÓGICA E SAÚ
DE INTEGRADA', 'ORTHODONTIC', 'ORTHOPRIDE', 'ORTODOCTOR FRANQUIAS', 'ORTOESTÉTICA', "O'STORE", 'ÓTICA CENTER', 'ÓTICA MARTINS', 'ÓTICA SOLAZI', 'ÓTICAS BRASIL', 'ÓTICAS CAROL', 'ÓTICAS DINIZ', 'ÓTICAS FER
RI ', 'OTICAS IPANEMA', 'ÓTICAS MERCADÓTICA', 'ÓTICAS RECRIS', 'ÓTICAS VÊNUS', 'OTICAS VIDA', 'ÓTICAS VIDERE', 'OTRIS', 'OUTLET DOS ÓCULOS', 'OUTLET LINGERIE', 'OVERBOARD', 'P DIVERTE', 'PABLO-BA', 'PACÍF
ICO SEA FOOD', 'PADARIA PET', 'PADRÃO ENFERMAGEM', 'PAMPILI', 'PANELINHAS DO BRASIL', 'PANOBIANCO ACADEMIA', 'PÃO & COMPANHIA', 'PAPÁ COMIDA DE CRIANÇA', 'PARADA IBIRAÇU', 'PARÇA', 'PARIS 6', 'PARIS SAINT
-GERMAIN ACADEMY', 'PARK EDUCATION', 'PARMÊ', 'PARMEGGIO GRELHADOS E LANCHES', 'PARTMED SAÚDE E MEDICINA', 'PASTELADA', 'PATRONI PIZZA ', 'PEÇA RARA BRECHÓ', 'PECORINO BAR E TRATTORIA', 'PEIXE AO CUBO', '
PEIXE NA REDE', 'PEIXINHO FELIZ', 'PELLO MENOS DEPILAÇÃO', 'PELO ZERO DEPILAÇÃO', 'PENTAGONAL SEGUROS', 'PEOPLE COMPUTAÇÃO', 'PERSONAL CLEAN PROFESSIONAL', 'PET SERVICES AU ALL & CO. EST. 2019', 'PETLAND'
, 'PEZINHO E CIA', 'PHARMAPELE', 'PHERFACE ESTÉTICA DA FACE', 'PHI CONCEPT', 'PHITOFARMA', 'PIASEG SEGUROS', 'PIC ENVIOS', 'PICANHA MANIA', 'PICCADILLY', 'PICORRUCHO MODA INFANTIL & ENXOVAIS', 'PILÃO PROF
ESSIONAL', 'PINK LASH', 'PINTA MUNDI TINTAS', 'PIONEIRA ARGAMASSAS ESPECIAIS', 'PIPELINE PISCINAS', 'PITICAS', 'PIZZA CREK', 'PIZZA DO RÃO', 'PIZZA FORFUN', 'PIZZA HUT', 'PIZZA PRIME', 'PIZZA STUDIO', 'PI
ZZA VIGNOLI', 'PIZZADOG', 'PLANETA IMAGINÁRIO', 'PLANETÁRIO', 'PLANO ORIGINAL', 'PLENA FACE', 'PLENA VISÃO VISTORIA VEICULAR', 'PLIE', 'POINT SUMMER & FOODS', 'POLYOTICA', 'POPDENTS', 'PORMADE', 'PORTAL D
A CIDADE', 'PORTAL SOLAR', 'PORTER ACESSO SEGURO', 'PORTO DO SABOR', 'PORTOBELLO SHOP', 'POSÉ', 'POSTNET', 'PREMIAPÃO', 'PREMYER', 'PREPARA CURSOS PROFISSIONALIZANTES', 'PRETZEL BITS', 'PRIME SAÚDE', 'PRI
ORIDADE 10', 'PROCOB', 'PRÓFISIO', 'PROJETO SOLAR', 'PROTEGE VISTORIA  FRANQUIAS ', 'PROVIN JOIAS', 'PRUDENTIAL', 'PUKET', 'PURE PILATES', 'PURIFIC', 'PURO AÇAÍ', 'PUSCO', 'QG JEITINHO CASEIRO', 'QÓCULOS
', 'QSORRISO CLÍNICAS ODONTOLÓGICAS', 'QUEM DISSE, BERENICE?', 'QUIERO CAFÉ', 'QUIKSILVER', 'QUÍMEA', 'QUISTO FRANQUIAS', 'QYON', 'RACE BOOTCAMP ', 'RAGAZZO', 'RAINHA', 'RALLYKIDS', 'RÃO BURGER', 'RÃO GRI
LL', 'RAPHAELLA BOOZ', 'RAPIDAO APP', 'RAPIDIN SALGADERIA', 'RECCO LINGERIE', 'RECEBACRED ', 'RECH TRATORES', 'RED BALLOON - INGLÊS P/ CRIANÇAS', 'REDE AUTORIZA SOLUÇÕES FINANCEIRAS', 'REDE CARTÓRIO FÁCIL
', 'REDE ELÉTRICA SOLAR ', 'REDE VITÓRIA SPA RESIDÊNCIA ASSISTIDA PARA IDOSOS ', 'REDEORTO', 'REDEVERDE JARDINS E ECONEGOCIOS', 'REFUGIO PATAGONIA', 'REGUS', 'REI DO MATE', 'REIBACK FRANQUIAS', 'REINO RUR
AL FRANCHISING', 'REMAX', 'RESERVA', 'RESTAURA JEANS', 'RHF Talentos', 'RHOPEN CONSULTORIA', 'RHS PREMIUM LIMPEZA PROFISSIONAL', 'RI HAPPY', 'RIDENT CLÍNICAS ODONTOLÓGICAS', 'RIO ARTE DERMATOLOGIC', 'RIO
ARTE ESTHETIC', 'RIO ARTE FOR MAN', 'RIO ARTE LASER', 'RIOLAX', 'ROASTED POTATO', 'ROBOMIND', 'ROCK & RIBS', 'ROCKFELLER LANGUAGE CENTER', 'ROSA MAKE', 'ROVAL PET - MANIPULAÇÃO VETERINÁRIA', 'ROYAL BEBIDA
S', 'ROYAL FACE', 'ROYAL TRUDEL', 'RSUP! CORRETORA DE SEGUROS', 'RURAL PAGO', 'S REDE SÊNIOR RESIDÊNCIA E HOSPEDAGEM', 'S.A. CASA DO SUSHI', 'S7 intercâmbio', 'SABOREATEYCAFE', 'SABORES DO NONNO', 'SAFFI
CONSULTORIA', 'SAHUR', 'SAL E BRASA GRILL', 'SALÃO MARLY', 'SALGADOS FUTURA', 'SAMELLO', 'SANCLÁ SAÚDE ANIMAL', 'SANTA CARGA', 'SANTA JANELA', 'SANTA LOLLA', 'SANTO KANTO RESTOBAR', 'SAPATOP', 'SAÚDE CLÍN
ICA POPULAR', 'SAUDE LIVRE ', 'SCHOOL OF ROCK', 'SCHUTZ', 'SCUDO CORRETORA DE SEGUROS', 'SEGCREDI', 'SEGENERGY', 'SEGURALTA - BOLSA DE SEGUROS', 'SEGURANÇA TOTAL', 'SELFIT ', 'SEMBLANT FRANCHISING', 'SENH
OR SMART', 'SENSE SPA EXPRESS', 'SERGIOS', 'SERVIÇOS DO FUTURO', 'SESTINI', 'SETH', 'SEU CHURROS', 'SEVEN ENGLISH - ESPAÑOL', 'SHEKINÁ BURGER & AÇAÍ', 'SHELL SELECT', 'SHOPMASP', 'SIDE WALK', 'SIMPLE ORGA
NIC', 'SIRÈNE FISH & CHIPS', 'SKYLER', 'SLEEP HOUSE ', 'SLIM CENTER ESTÉTICA E EMAGRECIMENTO', 'SMART FIT', 'SMARTCOMM', 'SNACKEL', 'SÓ MULTAS', 'SÓBRANCELHAS', 'SOBRANCELHAS DESIGN', 'SODIÊ DOCES', 'SOFÁ
 CAFÉ', 'SOLÁRIO PISCINA', 'SOLARON', 'SOLARPRIME', 'SOLARY VILLE', 'SOLUÇÕES INDUSTRIAIS', 'SOLUMEDI ', 'SOLUTION FOR LIFE', 'SONHO DOS PÉS', 'SORPACK EMBALAGENS', 'SORRIDENTS', 'SORRIFÁCIL CLÍNICA DENTÁ
RIA', 'SORRISO DIGITAL ODONTOLOGIA', 'SORRISO FÁCIL', 'SORRIX', 'SORVETE ITÁLIA', 'SORVETES ROCHINHA', 'SOULIER', 'SOW CAKE', 'SP IMPLANTES TRATAMENTOS ODONTOLÓGICOS', 'SPA & BRONZE', 'SPA EXPRESS', 'SPAC
E W', 'SPÉ O SPA DO PÉ', 'SPEASY IDIOMAS', 'SPEDINI TRATTORIA EXPRESSA', 'SPHERE INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL', 'SPIDER KICK', "SPIN'N SOUL", 'SPLASH', 'SPOLETO', 'SR. ESPETTO', 'SR. SORVETE', 'STALKER', 'STAR PO
INT', 'STELLA BARROS TURISMO', 'STERNA CAFÉ', 'STOCKYARDS ANGUS SANDWICH', 'STONE', 'STONIA ICE CREAMLAND', 'STOP&GO', 'STUDIO FISCAL - PLANEJAMENTO TRIBUTÁRIO', 'STUDIO GAMES', 'STUDIO VELOCITY', 'STYLEB
AR', 'SUAV', 'SUBURBANOS', 'SUBWAY', 'SUCÃO', 'SUCO BAGAÇO', 'SUCOS S/A', 'SUNGLASS HUT', 'SUPER APRENDIZ', 'SUPER DUPER BURGER', 'SUPER ESTÁGIOS', 'SUPER OTICA SÃO JOSÉ', 'SUPER VISÃO PERÍCIAS AUTOMOTIVA
S', 'SUPERA - GINÁSTICA PARA O CÉREBRO', 'SUPERGEEKS', 'SUPERSEG CÂMERAS. ALARMES. CERCA ELÉTRICA', 'SUSHI NAMOTO', 'SUSHICHIC', 'SUSHIJAPA CHAN', 'SUSHILOKO', 'SUSHIRÃO', 'SUSTENTARE', 'TACO', 'TACO BELL
', 'TAKI APP', 'TANTÔ TEMAKERIA', 'T-DONUTS ', 'TEA SHOP', 'TECH VISTORIAS', 'TECH4ME', 'TEMPLUM FRANCHISING', 'TERÇA DA SERRA CASA DE REPOUSO', 'TEREZA ZANCHI SHIATSU E BEM ESTAR', 'TFLOW', 'THE BEST AÇA
I', 'THE BODY SHOP', 'THE HOT MACHINE', 'THE JOY SCHOOL', 'THE KIDS CLUB - INGLÊS SÓ P/ CRIANÇAS', 'THE WAFFLE FACTORY', 'THE WAFFLE KING ', 'TICOMIA EVENTOS', "TICO'S BURGER", 'TIMES IDIOMAS', 'TINTAS MC
', 'TIOBÁK', 'TIP TOP', 'TO GO ATACADO DE CONGELADOS', 'TODESCHINI', 'TOP ENGLISH', 'TOP FROZEN AÇAÍ', 'TOPPER', 'TORTAMANIA', 'TORTERIA HAGUANABOKA', 'TOTAL AÇAI', 'TOTVS', 'TOUAREG CORRETORA DE SEGUROS'
, 'TOUTI', 'TRADICIONAL BOLOS & TORTAS', 'TRATABEM', 'TRIBBU FIT FOOD', 'TRILHA DO ACAI', 'TRUST INTERCÂMBIO CULTURAL E TURISMO', 'TT BURGER ', 'TURQUESA ESMALTERIA', 'TUTORE DESENVOLVIMENTO DE NEGÓCIOS',
 'TUTORES', 'TUTTI BIJOUX', 'TWICE', 'TZ VIAGENS', 'ULTRA ', 'UNHAS CARIOCAS', 'UNITED INSTITUTE', 'UP + VET MANIPULAÇÃO VETERINÁRIA', 'URBAN ARTS', 'USAFLEX', 'USINA DE MASSAS', 'UVA E VERDE', 'UZA ', 'V
 BEAUTY A MARCA DA BELEZA', 'V4 COMPANY', 'VA VAAPTY', 'VACCINI', 'VAI VOANDO ', 'VALE SAFE ', 'VALISERE', 'VALLORIZA SOLUÇÕES', 'VALOR OPERAÇÕES FINANCEIRAS', 'VAREJONLINE', 'VAZOLI', 'VERDE GHAIA', 'VER
TEX SOLUÇÕES PROFISSIONAIS', 'VEST CASA', 'VET FÓRMULA', 'VEZPA PIZZAS', 'VIA CERTA EDUCAÇAO PROFISSIONAL', 'VIA DIRETA', 'VIA LASER FRANCHISING', 'VIA MIA', 'VICO FARMA FARMÁCIA DE MANIPULAÇÃO', 'VICOFLO
RA', 'VIDA CARD ', 'VIDA LEVE', 'VILESOFT', 'VINHO & PONTO', 'VINO!', 'VIRTUOSA CLÍNICA ESTÉTICA', 'VITALPET', 'VIVA EVENTOS', 'VIVENDA DO CAMARÃO', 'VIZINHANDO BOTECAGEM DE RAIZ', 'VÓ ALZIRA CAFÉ', 'VOA'
, 'VOE VIAGENS E CÂMBIO', 'VOLL PILATES STUDIO', 'VRD GESTÃO DE BENEFÍCIOS', 'WCHIC', 'WERNER COIFFEUR', 'WINK ', 'WIZARD BY PEARSON', 'WORLD STUDY', 'WORLD TENNIS', 'WOWE CREDITO EM ACREDITAR', 'WPS - WE
LLNESS PERSONAL STUDIO', 'WSI BRASIL', 'XÔK`S CHOCOLATES', 'YAN PING', 'YANG', 'YÁZIGI', 'YES!', 'YES! COSMETICS', 'YOGOBERRY', 'YOLANDA BOTEQUIM', 'ZAITT', 'ZAPLUS CAR FRANCHISING', 'ZAPPIM', 'ZASTRAS BR
INQUEDOS', 'ZÉ COXINHA', 'ZZOPER STORE']}
2022-10-02 20:53:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-10-02 20:53:28 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (1 items) in: pages.json
2022-10-02 20:53:28 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 341,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 83126,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.006386,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 3, 3, 53, 28, 344814),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 1257614,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 3, 3, 53, 27, 338428)}
2022-10-02 20:53:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked pretty well now!!!